# getting the sum per month based on the data of another column if it is not null hence if it is null then it won't be added to the total

Tags: mysql, null, sum, case, calculated-columns

I have `view_dtr` with columns `Undertime`, `LateAM` and `LatePM` I need to get the `TotalUndertime` if either `LateAM` or `LatePM` `IS NOT NULL`.

```
|  EmpID  | DatePresent  |  Undertime  |  LateAM  |  LatePM  |
|  305001 | 2016-04-01   |  00:10:00   | 01:00:00 | 00:12:00 |
|  305001 | 2016-04-02   |  00:15:00   |          |          |
|  305001 | 2016-04-03   |  00:20:00   | 00:05:00 |          |
|  305001 | 2016-04-04   |  00:05:00   |          | 00:01:00 |
|  305002 | 2016-04-01   |  00:01:00   |          | 00:10:00 |
|  305002 | 2016-04-02   |  00:10:00   |          |          |
|  305002 | 2016-04-03   |  00:10:00   | 00:02:00 | 00:03:00 |
```

The `TotalUndertime` for `EmpID = 305001` should only be `00:35:00` and `EmpID = 305002` should be `00:11:00`. I keep on getting the whole sum using the `CASE` statement.

```
CASE WHEN LateAM IS NOT NULL AND Undertime IS NOT NULL 
        THEN SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Undertime))) 
    WHEN LatePM IS NOT NULL AND Undertime IS NOT NULL 
        THEN SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Undertime))) 
    ELSE NULL 
END AS TotalUndertime 
FROM view_dtr 
GROUP BY EmpID, MONTH(DatePresent)
```

Any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated. 
sorry for being a newbie.

Comment: Can you post data including EmpID and DatePresent columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the `CASE` *inside* the `SUM()`, because aggregation occurs after selecting.

You also don't need to filter out `Undertime = NULL` because those are ignored when summing.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN LateAM IS NOT NULL OR LatePM IS NOT NULL
                            THEN TIME_TO_SEC(UnderTime)
                       END)) AS TotalUndertime
FROM view_dtr
GROUP BY EmpID, MONTH(DatePresent)
```

Comment: I was overthinking the this statement `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Undertime)))`  thinking that CASE will help me. It did but i just placed it in the wrong. Thank you for this. I'm very grateful.